# Corda OS with Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, corda

The Corda OS 4.7 node is not able to successfully create a connection with the PostgreSQL database.

Following the guide here for running Corda node with PSQL from here:- https://medium.com/corda/cordapp-database-setup-production-perspective-2c400e60fae5

The guide seems to be outdated as many of the database configurations are not supported as of 4.7 OS version.

Igorning them the Corda node gives following error:-

```
...
Certificate signing request approved, storing private key with the certificate chain.
Private key 'cordaclientca' and its certificate-chain stored successfully.
Generating SSL certificate for node messaging service.
SSL private key and certificate chain stored in /opt/corda/certificates/sslkeystore.jks.
Generating trust store for corda node.
Node trust store stored in /opt/corda/certificates/truststore.jks.
Generating node identity certificate.
Node identity private key and certificate chain stored in identity-private-key.
Running database schema migration scripts ...
[ERROR] 14:04:07+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node registration: Could not find the database driver class. Please add it to the 'drivers' folder.
[ERROR] 14:04:07+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not find the database driver class. Please add it to the drivers directory. [Error Code: database-missing-driver For further information, please go to https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/error-codes.html]

   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         Computers are useless. They can only
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          give you answers.  -- Picasso
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 4.7 (75618ca) -------------------------------------------------------------


Logs can be found in                    : /opt/corda/logs
Running database schema migration scripts ...
[ERROR] 14:04:16+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not find the database driver class. Please add it to the drivers directory. [Error Code: database-missing-driver For further information, please go to https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/error-codes.html
```

Following is the config file of the node:-

```
p2pAddress = "127.0.0.1:10002"
rpcSettings {
    address: "0.0.0.0:10003"
    adminAddress: "0.0.0.0:10004"
    useSsl: true
    ssl {
        keyStorePath: "/opt/corda/certificates/sslkeystore.jks"
        keyStorePassword: "spass1"
    }
}
emailAddress = "xxxxxxx"
myLegalName = "O=XXXX,L=London,C=GB" 
keyStorePassword = "kpass1"
trustStorePassword = "trustpass"
devMode = false
rpcUsers= [
    {
        user=corda
        password=portal_password
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
networkServices {
    doormanURL="http://xxxxxx"
    networkMapURL="http://xxxxx"    
}
custom { jvmArgs = [ "-Xmx2048m", "-XX:+UseG1GC" ] }
dataSourceProperties {
    dataSource {
        password="my_password"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=party_a_schema"
        user="party_a"
    }
    dataSourceClassName="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
}
#database { 
   #transactionIsolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED
   #schema="party_a_schema"
   #runMigration=false
#}
# When JDBC driver is not present into the node's 'drivers' directory then add absolute path:
jarDirs = ['/opt/corda/node1/drivers']
sshd {
    port = 2222
}
```

All unsupported variables of `database` are commented out, `scheme` is added in the URL string only while I see that `transactionIsolationLevel` is hardcoded inside the node ever since. What could be the reason here?

Comment: Where is the driver for PSQL?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates lack of the database drivers. Please ensure you have an appropriate jar file in the "drivers" directory as mentioned in the article you linked.